# Counting necklaces with a fixed number of each bead

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, necklace-and-bracelets

I want to count the number of necklaces, with $n$ beads in total, where the alphabet of beads is $\{1,\ldots,k\}$, and where the number of beads with color $i$ is $n_i$. For example, if $n=4$, and $n_1 = n_2 = 2$, the following necklaces are the only possible
$$1122$$
$$1212$$

I have been able to find formulas for different variations of the problem, but not this one. If there is no nice formula, a generating function is always a nice compromise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a reasonably nice generating function coming from the [Pólya enumeration theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%B3lya_enumeration_theorem). It is given explicitly in, for example, [this blog post](http://qchu.wordpress.com/2009/06/21/gila-v-the-polya-enumeration-theorem-and-applications/): the number you want is the coefficient of $\prod r_i^{n_i}$ in

$$\frac{1}{n} \sum_{d | n} (r_1^{n/d} +\cdots + r_k^{n/d})^d \varphi \left( \frac{n}{d} \right).$$

Comment: What about a closed form solution, is that out of reach, or would posing certain constraints on the numbers change anything?

Comment: What do you mean by closed-form solution? Expanding the above out using the multinomial theorem gives you a pretty terrible formula in terms of multinomial coefficients. Is that a closed-form solution?

Comment: The counting problem stated above will be part of a larger counting problem, which I will in the end want to approximate, for example using Stirlings formula. So "a pretty terrible formula in terms of multinomial coefficients" sounds like the right direction.

Comment: Approximate in what regime?

Comment: What do you mean by "Approximate in what regime"? I am counting some combinations of cycles and spanning trees in cubic graphs, using the small-subgraph conditioning method.

Comment: I mean how large is $n$ relative to $k$ and the $n_i$?

Comment: There is no (non-trivial) bound on how large $k$ and $n_i$ can be, as far as I can see right now.

Comment: That's not what I mean. I mean is $n$ some very large number and $k$ very small compared to it? Or is $k$ approximately as large as $n$ and the $n_i$ are very small? Or something else?

Comment: I am sorry I was not clear enough. There is no relative bounds like that either.

Comment: Okay. Then I don't think you can do substantially better than the multinomial coefficients. (This is not so bad a formula if the number of divisors of $n$ is small, but in general...)