# Number of bracelets of length $12$ that can be obtained from “AABBBCCCDDDD” by permutation

Tags: combinatorics

[A similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/186157/counting-necklaces-with-a-fixed-number-of-each-bead) about *necklaces* has already been answered. I would like to know the very same thing regarding *bracelets*; that is, letting strings be equivalent under reflection.

For my practical purpose, I need to know the number of *bracelets* of length $12$ that can be obtained from “AABBBCCCDDDD” by permutation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is quite a number of these at
[MSE meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1868/list-of-generalizations-of-common-questions#13335)
written by  different users using  several equivalent variants  of the
standard notation.

Basically  you need  to  compute  the  cycle index  of  the
dihedral  group   on  twelve  elements  $Z(D_{12})$   and  do  careful
coefficient extraction. The answer is

$$[A^2 B^3 C^3 D^4] Z(D_{12})(A+B+C+D).$$

The cycle index is

$$Z(D_{12}) =
1/24\,{a_{{1}}}^{12}+{\frac {7\,{a_{{2}}}^{6}}{24}}+1/12\,{a_{{3}}}^
{4}+1/12\,{a_{{4}}}^{3}\\+1/12\,{a_{{6}}}^{2}+1/6\,a_{{12}}+1/4\,{a_{{
1}}}^{2}{a_{{2}}}^{5}$$

Recall the usual cycle index substitution which in the present case is
$$a_q^p = (A^q + B^q + C^q + D^q)^p.$$

Now $a_3^4$  produces multiples of three  in the exponents  so it does
not contribute. The terms in $a_2^6, a_4^3, a_6^2$ and $a_{12}$ do not
either  for  similar  reasons  (we  have  $\gcd(2,3,3,4)  =  1.$)  The
contribution from $a_1^{12}$ is

$$\frac{1}{24} {12\choose 2,3,3,4}.$$

The  term $a_1^2  a_2^5$ contributes  as follows.  As we  have  an odd
number of Bs and Cs one of each must come from $a_1^2$ which yields

$$\frac{1}{4} \times 2 \times {5\choose 1, 1, 1, 2}.$$

Adding these two yields the answer
$$\frac{1}{24} {12\choose 2,3,3,4}
+ \frac{1}{4} \times 2 \times {5\choose 1, 1, 1, 2}
= 11580.$$